# Social studio API create dashboard

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dashboard, social-studio

All,

I am currently trying the following with REST API in Social Studio

We have successfully

1. Use API to create topic profile
2. Use API to create keyword profile based upon the keywords used by the user

What is not working:

1. AFter the above mentioned steps, I want to use that to create a dashboard and sent the URL related to this dashboard. But unfortunately it does not look like Salesforce support the option to use the API to generate a dashboard for a user.

Has someone done this before or some ideas how to get this done?

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks, 
Regards, 
Marloes